# k8s replicaSet status is confusing

Tags: kubernetes

I have two services:

- bayonetta: backend clusterIp service, replicaset=2
- hide: frontend nodePort service, replicaset=1

I ran `kubectl get all`. I see the line 3 and 4 of replicaSet section has everything as 0, why do we have those two lines when nothing is available?

```
replicaset.apps/bayonetta-deployment-5b75868d89   2         2         2       3h36m
replicaset.apps/bayonetta-deployment-5c65f74c8b   0         0         0       176m
replicaset.apps/hide-deployment-575b6bc68d        0         0         0       3h12m
replicaset.apps/hide-deployment-66d955986b        1         1         1       155m
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably updated your `Deployments`, which results in scaling up new `ReplicaSets` and scaling down the existing ones.  See the Kubernetes docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment), with the example:

> Run `kubectl get rs` to see that the Deployment updated the Pods by creating a new ReplicaSet and scaling it up to 3 replicas, as well as scaling down the old ReplicaSet to 0 replicas.
>
> ```
> kubectl get rs
> ```
>
> The output is similar to this:
>
> ```
> NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
> nginx-deployment-1564180365   3         3         3       6s
> nginx-deployment-2035384211   0         0         0       36s
> ```

Answer (score 0):

K8S maintains multiple versions of ReplicationSets, this enables the rollback of a Deployment because of a bug or some other reason. More about it here ([1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment)). K8S maintains revisionHistoryLimit number of ReplicationSets which defaults to 10 ([2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#deploymentspec-v1-apps)).